# Allow changes for input properties without dirty check in Angular2

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have component with set method:

```
@Input('message')
set messageFromSocket(String message) {check(details)}
```

The message can be like 'some entity updated', and emitted from host component of many times:

```
@View(
    template: "<message-view [message]='message' [details]='details'></message-view>")
class Example implements OnInit {
  @override
  Future ngOnInit() async {
  ...
    socket.stream.listen((String data) async {
      details = (JSON.decode(data) as Map);
      message = (details['Message'] as String);
    });
  }
```

How can be messageFromSocket run every time when message in host updated?

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/b67d841c184a8256671d44947ffdddd5

Comment: I don't get what this question is about. Might be just me but making it more clear could improve chances for an answer.

Comment: Are you talking about `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Stateful ` and using the `setState` method ?
https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2/ChangeDetectionStrategy-class
https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2.core/ComponentState/setState

Comment: I added gist: https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/b67d841c184a8256671d44947ffdddd5
I need update some property (in gist it "messageCount") every time when it emit from host component. Now I get maximum messageCount = 2. It because "message" property didn't change. But I need get events of message every time. How I can do that?

Comment: what Angular version are you using. AFAIK `@View()` is long gone.

Comment: In my pubspec.lock angular2 is version 2.2.0